# Eclipse MapReduce plugin Hadoop 2.5.2

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-plugin, mapreduce

I know this question has been asked many times before, but I couldn't find any for this specific case, and this up-to-date. How do I install the Eclipse MapReduce plugin with Hadoop 2.5.2? I've found multiple tutorials addressing this for other versions, and I know that it can be compiled from [here](https://github.com/winghc/hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin), but that link, while it says 2.x, only says up to 2.4.1. I tried to compile it anyway using 2.5.2 using the following command:

```
ant jar -Dversion=2.4.1 -Dhadoop.version=2.5.2 -Declipse.home=/opt/eclipse -Dhadoop.home=/usr/local/hadoop -DBuildfile: build.xml
```

This attempted to compile, but then returned

> Warning: Could not find file /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar to copy.

Which makes sense, because the version of this jar in Hadoop 2.5.2 is 1.9.13.

Then I tried to use version 2.5.2, even though it is not mentioned in the jar, since it says that they support 2.x.

`ant jar -Dversion=2.5.2 -Dhadoop.version=2.5.2 -Declipse.home=/opt/eclipse -Dhadoop.home=/usr/local/hadoop -DBuildfile: build.xml`

In this case, it said BUILD SUCCESSFUL, but there was no output - no jar produced, and no output printed under the 'compile:' and 'jar:' steps.

I even tried downloading the compiled jar from [this guy's github](https://github.com/abhishekgoel137/hadoop-eclipse-plugins), but of course that didn't work either - it didn't show up in Eclipse when I added the jar to the plugins folder.

Is there any way to use the plugin with Hadoop 2.5.2, or do I have to downgrade to 2.4.1? I am using Ubuntu 14.0.4, Hadoop 2.5.2, and Eclipse Luna, but can downgrade that if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to run the map-reduce jobs from eclipse, then you need to

1. Create a Java project in eclipse
2. Add the hadoop jar files in the project reference library

Mapreduce programs can be compiled and executed from eclipse.

Note: By default eclipse considers the local filesystem for input and output files.

Comment: I know this, but I was hoping to use the plugin anyway, since it supposedly simplifies development. If that's not possible, I guess I'll give up. I've left this open for long enough and no one's answered, so I'm accepting your answer even though I was hoping for better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded hadoop-eclipse-plugin-2.6.0.jar (at the time of writing this is the latest) from https://github.com/winghc/hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin/tree/master/release and pasted the jar file in the plugin folder of the Eclipse. It gave me "Map/Reduce" Wizard and I got the "Run on Hadoop" Option!!  I am using Eclipse Luna.
  you could use the "Hadoop" Wizard to define the HDFS Server.